# lshw not showing network

Tags: networking

Output:

```
{User}@{Computer}:~$ sudo lshw -class network
{User}@{Computer}:~$
```

Another Test:

```
{User}@{Computer}:~$ lspci
00:00.0 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 Memory Controller (rev a1)
00:01.0 ISA bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 LPC Bridge (rev a2)
00:01.1 SMBus: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 SMBus (rev a2)
00:01.2 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 Memory Controller (rev a2)
00:02.0 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 USB 1.1 Controller (rev a3)
00:02.1 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 USB 2.0 Controller (rev a3)
00:04.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 PCI bridge (rev a1)
00:05.0 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 High Definition Audio (rev a2)
00:06.0 IDE interface: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 IDE (rev a2)
00:07.0 Bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 Ethernet (rev a2) <<---- Network Card????
00:08.0 IDE interface: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 SATA Controller (rev a2)
00:08.1 IDE interface: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 SATA Controller (rev a2)
00:09.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 PCI Express bridge (rev a2)
00:0b.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 PCI Express bridge (rev a2)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] HyperTransport Technology Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Miscellaneous Control
01:05.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): LSI Corporation FW322/323 (rev 70)
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G96 [GeForce 9500 GT] (rev a1)
```

If you look at 00:07.0 I believe that is the network card.  However lshw doesnt show it.

I mainly need information on network speed 10MBpS/100MBsP/1000MBpS

Though knowing why my system isn't working would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems no one answered this, and to be honest, until today I couldn't have either. It just happens, however, that I just picked up a shuttle box to serve as a file/print server that is using a mini-itx planar with the nvidia 430 chipset.

First, I couldn't see a network device at all, until I set the MAC Media Interface BIOS option to RGMII.

Then I was able to see the device in lspci, and it appears exactly as yours does (same bus address even).

So the key to your question is that it does not appear to the system as a network class device, but rather a bridge.  so if you do this, you'll see it:

```
bladernr@transit:~$ sudo lshw -class bridge
[Unnecessary stuff snipped]
  *-bridge
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: MCP61 Ethernet
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 7
       bus info: pci@0000:00:07.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: a2
       serial: 00:01:2e:35:2d:d3
       size: 1000000000
       capacity: 1000000000
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: bridge pm msi ht bus_master cap_list ethernet physical mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=forcedeth driverversion=0.64 duplex=full ip=192.168.0.107 latency=0 link=yes maxlatency=20 mingnt=1 multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:43 memory:fe02d000-fe02dfff ioport:ec00(size=8)
[Unnecessary stuff snipped]
```

Comment: Interesting... you seem to have figured it out!